# Add dropdown login to right side of navbar

Tags: html, css

My aim goal is to be able to do a drop down login/register form however I am stuck on how I could put the "Login / Register" part at the far right of the navbar, I have tried to do a new div and float it left but it seems to overlap the navbar items, any suggestions would be appreciated.

HTML:

```css
div#navi{
 background-color: #C23B22;
}
div#navi_wrapper{
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 width: 1080px;
}
div#navi ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
div#navi ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
div#navi ul li a, visited{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 16px;
 display: block;
}
div#navi ul li a:hover{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #AE351E;
}
div#navi ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}
div#navi ul ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
 border-top: 0;
 min-width: 100px;
}
div#navi ul ul li{
 display: block;
}
#navi ul li li a,visited{
 color: #C23B22;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#navi ul ul li a:hover{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #C23B22;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="navi">
  <div id="navi_wrapper">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">REVIEWS</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">PC Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">Playstation 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">XBOX One</a></li>
     </ul>
     <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">ABOUT US</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">CONTACT</a></li>

    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q07jv74x/

Comment: can you include you attempt in the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using the HTML element's ID to set the CSS properties which will override the CSS properties of any nested elements. I would recommend using Classes instead:

HTML:

```
<div class="navi">
        <div class="navi_wrapper">
            <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">REVIEWS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">PC Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">Playstation 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">XBOX One</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pages/home.php', 'primaryContent');">CONTACT</a></li>       
           <li class="navi_float_right"><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navi{
    background-color: #C23B22;
}
.navi_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}    
.navi ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.navi ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.navi ul li a, visited{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px;
    display: block;
}
.navi ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #AE351E;
}
.navi ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
.navi ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-top: 0;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.navi ul ul li{
    display: block;
}
.navi ul li li a,visited{
    color: #C23B22;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navi ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #C23B22;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navi_float_right{
  float: right;
}
```

I also removed the width property from the `navi_wrapper` CSS class as you typically want navbars to extend the full width of the screen.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pLofgdoy/1/